# 1 Cron Job for 30 tasks Vs 30 Cron Jobs performing 1 task each

Tags: linux, cron

Will running 1 Cron Job for performing 30 tasks Vs 30 Cron Jobs performing 1 each make any difference on server load? Or will both the conditions create the same load on server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Running one cron job which executes 30 tasks is more efficient.

Since I'm assuming they will all run at the same time, you are only tying up one process instead of 30 difference processes.

Although this was not part of the original question - maintaining 30 different scripts will be a headache. Much easier to make changes to one script, as mu 無 also pointed out below.

Comment: Can you prove that or do we just have to believe you? :)

Comment: Think about mailing 30 letters/emails with only 1 instruction each compared to mailing one letter/email with all 30 instructions.

Comment: You have to open each one up - read it - close it - find the next one - etc

Comment: Not a "totally wrong" analogy - perhaps not the best, but the answer is still correct.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on whether all the tasks have to be synchronous or can they be serialized to run one after the other.

If they have to be all synchronous, then you will have to run them all simultaneously and hence will need 30 separate jobs, leading to a spike on the server. If they can be run one after the other, its better to schedule them as a single cron job.

If you schedule 30 cron jobs even though they could have been serialized, that would cause unnecessary drain on your server resource, because now they are synchronized even though they aren't needed to be, and you have 29 extra processes fighting out for ram, CPU, network resources.

Also, if the tasks are all similar, I would prefer 1 single cron script for them, with the script calling the tasks individually, instead of having to maintain 30 separate cron entries in crontab.